# C program waits for the execution of the command sent with SSH

Tags: c, linux, ssh

I am trying to send commands via SSH to a remote system that I will need to comunicate through the serial port. When I send a command that is executed immediately everything works fine but when I send a command to the client that runs my program which hangs and waits for the serial data, the rest of my c code is not executed. My code looks like this.

```
 FILE* remf = popen("ssh DestinationPC > remoteoutput.txt", "w");
 if (!remf) { perror("popen ssh failed"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
 fprintf(remf, "./IOexpander \n");
 fprintf(remf, "./Serial \n");
 fclose(remf);
```

The first line (./IOexpander) works fine and turns some LEDS on. Without the second line the execution coninues. But when I add the second line (when I try to run  any program that does not terminate immediately), the lines below the code above are not executed.

How can I have my c program running without waiting for the execution of the command in the client?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Probably the wrong approach. Consider using [libssh](https://www.libssh.org/) instead

Comment: `popen` is wrong approach for bi-directional IO. Output to `remoteoutput.txt` might be buffered in ways, which you can't control. Giving *ssh* the command line switch to force allocation to pseudo terminal *might* help. Also, you might want to catch *stderr* output as well and see if something is printed there. But to make it robust, you will need file descriptors for *ssh* process *stdin*, *stdout* and *stderr* all, and use `select`/`poll` to access them all simultaneously. Unless this is learning exercise, use a library as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Since the code has multiple scripts execution, it might help rule out the script errors by running ssh to the box and executing the scripts.

**$ ssh user@hostname "./IOexpander  && ./Serial \n"**

Answer (score 0):

stdout is buffered (see [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html) & [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html)), and so might be the stdin of the forked `ssh` process (see [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html))

You probably should end your `fprintf` format control strings with `\n`.

You certainly should wisely use [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) at appropriate places.

BTW, I would suggest avoiding `popen`-ing some `ssh` and using [libssh](https://www.libssh.org/) instead.

Perhaps your remote `./Serial` is somehow failing. You should check that. Your current approach don't handle well the failure of remote programs.

Comment: Yes, I actually use \n but forgot to add here. I have also tried it with fflush(), but didn't work.  Probably I should check libssh. Thanks!